# Column =Avg(Fields!Counts.Value) doesn't work

Tags: reporting-services, average

I'm trying to get a simple column average to work in SSRS(2016 I Believe).

If I can't get the column average I'll settle for a correct row count (917)
This doesn't work either =CountRows()
This also doesn't work = RunningValue(Fields!Counts.Value,count,"Customers")

Here are the formulas I tried that don't work:[image: Excel Export]

This should be a simple expression. Is this a bug in SSRS?
[image: SSRS Screen Shot]

Comment: A sample of data would be useful but you seem to be, in your first expression, summing the values in the count field and then dividing by the number of distinct values in the column. Is that what you intended?